# Extract a .rar file using a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file which extracts a .rar file using WinRAR
to C:\Program Files\

Please help

I tried the following code

```
set rar=%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\RAR.exe

set unrar=%programFiles%\WinRAR\UnRAR.exe
```

and then you compress like this:

```
"%rar%" a "drop location" "target location"
```

or decompress like this:

```
%unrar% e "target location"
```

but I don't seem to see an option here which shows where the target rar file is. Please help me.

Answer (score 6):

Check this page: https://cects.com/using-the-winrar-command-line-tools-in-windows/

Basically (taken from that site):

`rar a -r yourfiles.rar *.txt c:\yourfolder` to compress something

`unrar x c:\yourfile.rar *.gif c:\extractfolder\` to uncompress something

The *.txt and *.gif are used for filtering file types and can be omitted.

At the bottom of the page are also links to two example batch files.

Comment: No problem :) Do you mind marking my answer as correct?